# Pandas DataFrame to Excel: Vertical Alignment of Index

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

Given the following data frame:
import pandas as pd

```
d=pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','a','b','b'],
               'b':['a','b','c','d'],
               'c':[1,2,3,4]})
d=d.groupby(['a','b']).sum()
d
```

[image]

I'd like to export this with the same alignment with respect to the index (see how the left-most column is centered vertically?).
The rub is that when exporting this to Excel, the left column is aligned to the top of each cell:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_out.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
workbook  = writer.book
f=workbook.add_format({'align': 'vcenter'})
d.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

...produces...

[image]

Is there any way to center column A vertically via XLSX Writer or another library?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try the structure [here](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#set_align). It looks similar to what you've done, but I don't know enough about the xlsxwriter library to know if they're identical.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are trying to change the formatting of the header so you should first reset the default header settings

```
from pandas.io.formats.excel import ExcelFormatter
ExcelFormatter.header_style = None
```

Then apply the formatting as required

```
format = workbook.add_format()
format.set_align('center')
format.set_align('vcenter')

worksheet.set_column('A:C',5, format)
```

here is complete working code

```
d=pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','a','b','b'],
               'b':['a','b','c','d'],
               'c':[1,2,3,4]})
d=d.groupby(['a','b']).sum()

pd.core.format.header_style = None

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_out.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
workbook  = writer.book
d.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

format = workbook.add_format()
format.set_align('center')
format.set_align('vcenter')

worksheet.set_column('A:C',5, format)
writer.save()
```

Comment: Instead of using 'center' i am using 'left' and the text still gets aligned to the center

Comment: @acuriousengineer Same here :(

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'pandas.core' has no attribute 'format'` it seems that it no longer works...

Comment: Fixed - edited as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/42234793/27938