# Pandas DataFrame to Excel cell alignment

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I noticed that for `string` in `Dataframe` will keep left align in Excel and for `numerical` value will keep right align in Excel.

How do we set the desired alignment we wanted when exporting `DataFrame` to Excel? Example: `Center Alignment`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"colname1": ["a","b","c","d"], "colname2": [1,2,3,4]})

with pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx") as writer:
    df.to_excel(
        writer,
        index=False,
        header=False,
    )
```

Comment: Strings at left and numerical at right are the default behaviour in Excel. To change format i think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41364380/pandas-dataframe-to-excel-vertical-alignment-of-index)  may be helpful and because it's outdated, also check [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42234622/pandas-raising-attributeerror-module-pandas-core-has-no-attribute-format)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the styles of the dataframe using the [Styler object](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.html#pandas.io.formats.style.Styler), which uses the same conventions as CSS. The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) has a great primer on the different ways of styling your dataframes.

For a simple solution to your example, you can set the desired alignment by first creating a function:

```
def align_center(x):
    return ['text-align: center' for x in x]
```

Then write it to Excel while applying the function you just defined:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx") as writer:
    df.style.apply(align_center, axis=0).to_excel(
        writer,
        index=False,
        header=False
    )
```

This will center-align the cells in the Excel file. For an exhaustive list of available text alignment options I would suggest the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align).

Comment: in this case `applymap` would be simpler: `df.style.applymap(lambda _: 'text-align: center').to_excel(...)`

Answer (score 5):

Or even better with just `set_properties`:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx") as writer:
    df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center'}).to_excel(
        writer,
        index=False,
        header=False,
    )
```

This aligns all text to the center.

This will work because it sets the property `text-align` to `center`. Then with the context manager instance (`with` statement), it can write to an excel file.