# How to align the CSV column values to left side using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[[image]]

As shown in the screen shot, I want to align the B-column values to the left side & python script should save to the same csv file.

Comment: CSV files do not carry formating information, are you looking to save as an excel file?

Comment: If yes, for excel could you please help here?

Answer (score 0):

.csv-files have no formating information. If you want to write the dataframe in an excel with an alignment, please try this:

[pandas-dataframe-to-excel-vertical-alignment-of-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41364380/pandas-dataframe-to-excel-vertical-alignment-of-index)

Maybe is that's a possible solution for you.
You have to edit `format.set_align('vcenter')` to `format.set_align('left')`

You get additional information here => [set_align()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#set_align)

Try it and give me feed, if it works :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

CSVs have no formatting, so that is not possible. However, if you are wanting an excel file, this will use xlsx writer's formats, the documentation for this can be found [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html).

You need to use `pd.ExcelWriter`, write your df and create a format to left align (you can add more formatting if required) and set the columns A to C to be left aligned as below:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('filename.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer)
left = workbook.add_format({'align' : 'left'})
worksheet.set_column('A:C', 8, center)
writer.save()
```